# Como obtengo los datos de un Task<ActionResult> para mostrarlos en una vista de MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un método en mi api de net core que me devuelve un ActionResult envuelto en un Task :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMobileAplicacion(){
   ....
   return Ok(aplicaciones);
}
```

Ese api **NO** esta hecho con Entity Framework sino con métodos propios. Ahora lo que quiero es hacer una parte visual para el backend por decirlo de alguna forma sin embargo cuando trato de hacer lo siguiente en mi controlador MVC :

```
       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var lista =new MobileAplicacionController();

            var result = lista.GetMobileAplicacion();

            ViewBag.aplicaciones = result;

            return View(ViewBag.aplicaciones);
        }
```

Me tira el siguiente error:

```
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult>' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Como puedo convertir el actionresult en un ienumerable o en un viebag que pueda mostrar en una vista razor?

Comment: Me late que recién inicias con este framework, te sugiero revisar el workshop que hice de 4 horas maratónicas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&t=1s es un extracto de un curso de más de 30 horas que llevé en la Microsoft Virtual Academy :)

Comment: Microsoft Virtual Academy ya no existe hasta donde yo sé.

Comment: Y si soy relativamente nuevo en MVC

Comment: En efecto. Te estoy hablando de varios años atrás. Ahora está Microsoft.com/Learn

Answer (score 7):

Primero te paso al [enlace en stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801094/how-to-get-the-values-from-a-taskiactionresult-returned-through-an-api-for-uni/53379617#53379617) donde yo obtuve la respuesta, de la cual participé.

Aquí te muestro con un test unitario cómo obtener el valor *dentro* de:

```
Task<IActionResult>
```

Si bien no es exactamente el mismo escenario que lo que tu dices, si es el mismo objetivo, obtener el valor.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Get_ReturnsAnArea()
{
    // Arrange
    string areaId = "SomeArea";
    Area expectedArea = new Area() { ObjectId = areaId, AreaNameEn = "TestArea" };

    var restClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
    restClient.Setup(client => client.GetAsync<Area>(It.IsAny<string>(), false)).ReturnsAsync(expectedArea);

    var controller = new AreasController(restClient.Object);

    //// Act

    // We now await the call
    IActionResult actionResult = await controller.Get(areaId);

    // We cast it to the expected response type
    OkObjectResult okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;

    // Assert

    Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedArea, okResult.Value);

   // We cast Value to the expected type
    Area actualArea = okResult.Value as Area;
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedArea.AreaNameEn.Equals(actualArea.AreaNameEn));
}
```

Lo principal aquí es obtener el valor (value) que te devuelve el ActionResult.
En mi caso eso lo puedes ver en:

```
OkObjectResult okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
var valor = okResult.Value; // esto te lo he puesto a modo ilustrativo.
```

Entiendo que **View** tiene que recibir una 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' pero le estás pasando un **Task< Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult >**

Por tanto, primero hay que hacer el **await** del metodo en tu caso **GetMobileAplicacion** ya que es asíncrono para luego obtener el valor del **ActionResult**.

Retomando tu ejemplo y modificándolo un poco creo que podría funcionar así:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var lista =new MobileAplicacionController();

            var result = await lista.GetMobileAplicacion(); //ya que es async

            ViewBag.aplicaciones = result.value; 

            return View(ViewBag.aplicaciones);
        }
```

**Editado:**

En relación a tu método de tu API de **.NET Core** no te es necesario *modificar el controlador en el api y decirle el tipo de datos que devuelve* ya que  [OkObjectResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) recibe un *object* y una des su propiedad (heredada) **Value** es de tipo **object** como puedes ver aquí

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
{
    public class ObjectResult : ActionResult, IStatusCodeActionResult, IActionResult
    {
        public ObjectResult(object value);

        [ActionResultObjectValueAttribute]
        public object Value { get; set; }
```

Por tanto tu Controlador podría ser así sin necesidad de especificar el tipo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetStringArray()
        {
            return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });  //Devuelve un string Array
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetInt(int id)
        {
            return Ok(5); //Devuelve un int
        }
    }
```

Es por eso que en el Unit Test que te puse de ejemplo al principio te puse otra Clase (Area) ya que de esa forma da igual el tipo devuelto porque queda **envuelto** dentro del *Value* del *ActionResult*.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Esta aunque no era del todo la respuesta fue la que más me ayudo a resolver el problema

Comment: En ese caso, coloca el código que has realizado como respuesta y en 24 horas la marcas como aceptada :)

Answer (score 2):

Te en cuenta que estás llamando a un Web Api que funciona de manera asíncrona `public async Task<ActionResult> GetMobileAplicacion()`.

Para poder obtener correctamente el resultado, tienes dos opciones:

**1 - De forma asíncrona - async / await**

Debes transformar la Acción `Index()` de tu Controlador MVC en asíncrona:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var lista = new MobileAplicacionController();
        var result = await lista.GetMobileAplicacion();
        ViewBag.aplicaciones = result;
        return View(ViewBag.aplicaciones);
    }
```

**2 - De forma síncrona - Result**

Si no importa que el proceso sea síncrono, puedes utilizar `Result` para obtener directamente el resultado:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var lista = new MobileAplicacionController();
        var result = lista.GetMobileAplicacion().Result;
        ViewBag.aplicaciones = result;
        return View(ViewBag.aplicaciones);
    }
```

Comment: Esta solución no funciono!!

Comment: Tira el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas devolver una collecion de ActionResult de la siguiente manera

Para un objeto simple

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<MiTipo>> GetMobileAplicacion()
```

Para una coleccion

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<MiTipoDeColeccion<MiTipo>>> GetMobileAplicacion()
```

Y luego sacar el resultado de la tarea con `Wait()` / `Result` / o `async y await` como otros ya lo han indicado.

Comment: ¿Porqué devolverías una collection de ActionResult?

Comment: es un error comun, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816947/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-badrequestobjectresult, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no entiendo muy bien porqué quieres llamar un ActionResult desde otro ActionResult, puede que esto te funcione:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {           
            var lista =new MobileAplicacionController();    
            var result = lista.GetMobileAplicacion().Result;    
            ViewBag.aplicaciones = result;    
            return View(ViewBag.aplicaciones);
        }
```

básicamente, al ser un Task, invocado desde un método no asincrono, debes acceder a Result para que se evalue el Task y obtengas el resultado de la misma.

Ahora, creo que la forma correcta para ejecutar un action desde otro Action es como se describe aqui: [ControllerBase.RedirectToAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @Sebastian Inones fue la que más me ayudo:

Primero tuve que modificar el controlador en el api  y decirle el tipo de datos que devuelve:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MobileAplicacion>> GetMobileAplicacion()
```

y segundo en el controlador MVC tuve que pegar este código:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

            var controller = new MobileAplicacionController();

            var action =await controller.GetMobileAplicacion();

            OkObjectResult okResult =  action.Result as OkObjectResult;

            ViewBag.aplicaciones = okResult.Value;

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: En mi respuesta original  he agregado cómo podrías tener tu *Controller* ya que **no creo** que te haga falta incluir el tipo a devolver como muestra el ejemplo que  he añadido al final.

Comment: Si fue necesario. Si no le pongo lo que devuelve no me funciona.